# When I expand one tab section, all carat arrows are facing upwards. only selected arrows should show up

Tags: angular, html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfsqC.png)Actually there are four tabs, on each tab carat click function is there.
When I expand one tab section, all carat arrows are facing upwards. only selected arrows should show up

```js
accountSelection(account) {
    if (!this.selectedAccount || account.accountId !== this.selectedAccount.accountId) {
      this.selectedAccount = account;
      this.selectedAccountTransactions = this.transactionData.unrealizedGainLossDetails.filter(acc => acc.accountId === this.selectedAccount.accountId);
      this.initialPaging();
    } else {
      this.selectedAccount = undefined;
      this.selectedAccountTransactions = undefined;
      this.unrealizedTransaction = undefined;
    }
    this.cd.detectChanges();
  }
```

```html
<span class="col-md-1 p-0 acc-carat col-sm-1" (click)="accountSelection(account)" *ngIf="!transactionsInfo.loading">
                            <i _ngcontent-c2="" *ngIf="!selectedAccount " class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <i _ngcontent-c2="" *ngIf="selectedAccount" class="fa fa-caret-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>
```

Comment: Post your `ngFor` code too

Comment: Instead of selectedAccount use some boolean variable and toggle on click isClicked = !isClicked

Answer (score 0):

Even you can set using new property of object like this -

```
<span class="col-md-1 p-0 acc-carat col-sm-1" (click)="accountSelection(account)" *ngIf="!transactionsInfo.loading">
    <i _ngcontent-c2="" *ngIf="account?.open" class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i _ngcontent-c2="" *ngIf="!account?.open" class="fa fa-caret-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</span>

accountSelection(account) {
    ..... //Set (open = false) for every item in array
    account.open = true;
    this.cd.detectChanges();
  }
```

Right now you are using global variable `selectedAccount` which is being updated every time you call function.

Comment: Hi Pardeep , first of all thanks for your response , I will try this and I will let know